# Swift UIToolBar Append UIBarButtonItem Items

Tags: ios, swift

I’m not getting the syntax right. Anybody know what's missing here?  I’m using Xcode 6 beta 3 and I'm trying to dynamically add a toolbar item to my (manually added) toolbar in my viewDidLoad. There are two issues. First, I can't append the items in my toolbar to an array. Second, while the compiler allows my call to append (+=), when it finishes, the array is still empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var items = [AnyObject]() // Zero items, mutable, right?
//        items += buttonBar.items  // Not allowed --> compiler error

    if let displayModeButton = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem() {
        items += displayModeButton // Still zero items after append
    }
    buttonBar.items = items // Still zero items after append

}
```

buttonBar is an IBOutlet that is set in IB.

Comment: What's the compiler error? Hard to say how to fix without knowing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to add the toolbar's items by force unwrapping the array. It seems like that shouldn't be necessary, since the `items` property is implicitly unwrapped, but that made the compiler let it through.

I'm not sure why your `items += displayModeButton` line isn't working -- are you sure it's being called? This code adds a button with the title "Another" to my toolbar:

```
var items = [AnyObject]()

items += self.barButton.items!
items += UIBarButtonItem(title: "Another", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: "")
self.barButton.items = items
```

Comment: So after some wrestling with the code, I realized that the displayModeButton was actually getting added. The debugger just wasn't correctly reporting the count to me. I put the count into a variable and it was updating correctly. Also, the reason that button wasn't showing up was because I had set the preferredDisplayMode on the split view controller to "Automatic" which was preventing the button from displaying. Anyhow, thanks for your help. I may eventually love Swift, but not today. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Below code worked for me:

```
    let keyboardDoneButtonView = UIToolbar()
    keyboardDoneButtonView.sizeToFit()

    let flexBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("doneClicked"))

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(flexBarButton)
    items.append(doneButton)


    keyboardDoneButtonView.items = items
```

Hope this helps!!